# In drupal 7, get a taxonomy token replaced in a panelizer webform

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-webform

Here's my scenario: I have a drupal 7 site. It's categorized by a taxonomy. Each taxonomy term is panelized to display its main page. For each of those pages, I want to add a webform that would allow the visitor to email the person responsible for that area. The responsible person is defined in a hidden field on the taxonomy term.

If I add custom content to the panelizer page with the token

`%taxonomy_term:field-generic-email-address`

the email address is displayed. However, I need to get that into the webform, and I can't get it to pull the value from the token - it just displays that exact text (I'm trying to add it to a hidden field, but I'm sticking it into the body just to see, and in either place, it shows the token text instead of replacing it with the email). Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out a module called EntityForm https://drupal.org/project/entityform

It allows you to use regular Drupal fields to build a user-submittable form.

There are other ways to do this, but this method may allow you to get what you want and more.